# No completly encrypt and mount LVM during boot after update to bookworm

Tags: linux, boot, debian, lvm, luks

few day ago I update system and then problems begin to happen.
During boot I were thrown to initramfs (no drive found), so only option to continue is to do command below:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md127 luks-storage
fsck /dev/mapper/LVM-*
exit
```

Then boot continue asking again for password for drive which is mounted in initramfs.
My configuration is as description below:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,UUID,FSTYPE
sda                                                                                                                 
├─sda1                                                                       d94878a2-2301-dc37-f655-585791669c74   linux_raid_member
│ └─md0                                         /boot                        37e9be99-c04f-4051-a2c1-c2dc4dd96bb8   ext3
└─sda2                                                                       43c84e01-851d-6a97-9483-991c352554b2   linux_raid_member
  └─md1                                                                      09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c   crypto_LUKS
    └─luks-09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c                              lIGpdj-99Hp-Cb9o-99g7-5LTz-tsOK-0tbcNA LVM2_member
      ├─LVM-MAIN                                /                            f5b36841-c7eb-4b68-940b-9161748d6498   ext4
      └─LVM-HOME                                /home                        2f622091-fb8d-46a4-afed-3bf45a2d8f7c   ext4
sdb                                                                                                                 
├─sdb1                                                                       d94878a2-2301-dc37-f655-585791669c74   linux_raid_member
│ └─md0                                         /boot                        37e9be99-c04f-4051-a2c1-c2dc4dd96bb8   ext3
└─sdb2                                                                       43c84e01-851d-6a97-9483-991c352554b2   linux_raid_member
  └─md1                                                                      09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c   crypto_LUKS
    └─luks-09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c                              lIGpdj-99Hp-Cb9o-99g7-5LTz-tsOK-0tbcNA LVM2_member
      ├─LVM-MAIN                                /                            f5b36841-c7eb-4b68-940b-9161748d6498   ext4
      └─LVM-HOME                                /home                        2f622091-fb8d-46a4-afed-3bf45a2d8f7c   ext4
sdc                                                                                                                 
├─sdc1                                                                       d94878a2-2301-dc37-f655-585791669c74   linux_raid_member
│ └─md0                                         /boot                        37e9be99-c04f-4051-a2c1-c2dc4dd96bb8   ext3
└─sdc2                                                                       43c84e01-851d-6a97-9483-991c352554b2   linux_raid_member
  └─md1                                                                      09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c   crypto_LUKS
    └─luks-09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c                              lIGpdj-99Hp-Cb9o-99g7-5LTz-tsOK-0tbcNA LVM2_member
      ├─LVM-MAIN                                /                            f5b36841-c7eb-4b68-940b-9161748d6498   ext4
      └─LVM-HOME                                /home                        2f622091-fb8d-46a4-afed-3bf45a2d8f7c   ext4
sdd                                                                                                                 
└─sdd1                                                                       d1e924a4-75d2-b354-b435-49b8215cca95   linux_raid_member
  └─md127                                                                    838dc7ce-4a8b-4955-9eec-8aac7b90ab51   crypto_LUKS
    └─luks-storage                                                           OjsyvA-TI3t-pzw9-wwhA-jmDB-f3yc-cU6qqF LVM2_member
      └─LVM-STORAGE                             /storage                     94a866eb-7527-453c-b102-69e93f926692   ext4
sde                                                                                                                 
└─sde1                                                                       d1e924a4-75d2-b354-b435-49b8215cca95   linux_raid_member
  └─md127                                                                    838dc7ce-4a8b-4955-9eec-8aac7b90ab51   crypto_LUKS
    └─luks-storage                                                           OjsyvA-TI3t-pzw9-wwhA-jmDB-f3yc-cU6qqF LVM2_member
      └─LVM-STORAGE                             /storage                     94a866eb-7527-453c-b102-69e93f926692   ext4
nvme0n1                                                                                                             
└─nvme0n1p1                                                                  67132919-c255-493c-9f69-31b10b675424   swap
```

In short raid1 from 3 disk for system and additional 2 disks in raid 1 for additional storage, and swap on nvme.

grub config file below:

```
cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Debian"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 cryptdevice=UUID=lIGpdj-99Hp-Cb9o-99g7-5LTz-tsOK-0tbcNA:luks-09d8a6ab-1159-4e40-b83f-1f595806c05c root=/dev/mapper/LVM-MAIN quit"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos insmod modraid cryptdisk luks2 luks lvm mdraid1x ext2"

GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

To me it look like LVM cannot by partialy mount during boot, but I have no idea how to workaround it.

All sugestions welcome.
Have a nice day
Piotr

Comment: try the accepted answer there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230349/how-to-correctly-install-grub-on-a-soft-raid-1 . On Debian you can configure it so it remembers to do this  at upgrades on all drives that were mentioned with `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` (for BIOS, which I suspect you're using). Which by experience is a good idea even for non-raid: sda, sdb, ... don't always keep their order. That's also one reason to have partitions (grub-install won't install if there's none, because it doesn't know what spare space is available for it).